# Cucumber Environment variable in tag

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have a test pack where the tests run in Selenium_webdriver (Chrome) by default and have an option to run in Poltergeist via `ENV['headless']` in the env.rb file.  The headless tests get used in deployment (no browser installed on box).

I have some tests that are specific to being run headless such as checking status codes, response headers etc. I was wondering if there is a way I could use a hook to say while `headless=true` do x, y or z.

I've tried using tags but this interferes with the tests when they are run in browser.

Something like:

```
AfterStep (ENV['headless']) do
   if page.status_code == 200      
    check_xss_settings
   end
end
```

Is it possible to do what I want?

Thank you

Comment: What is the problem you are having when you use tags? If you add the tag say "@Headless" for features or scenarios for deployment and use the --tags options with the "@Headless" tags. For browser tests no tags options, or if you do not want to run deployment tests negate the "@Headless" option using "~@Headless".

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713935/how-to-implement-different-data-for-cucumber-scenarios-based-on-environment

Comment: Thanks fabersky, it's a good read but it appears to be aimed at java instead of Ruby

Comment: @Grasshopper I was finding that when I was tagging '@heading', I needed something in that hook that would overwrite the default driver from selenium to poltergeist. This would then change the default driver from selenium when I wasn't using that headless tag.  I've posted a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified where I was going wrong.

In my hook, I was using the following:

```
AfterStep (ENV['headless']) do
    if page.status_code == 200      
    check_xss_settings
   end
end
```

By doing this, I was able to achieve my result:

```
AfterStep do
  if ENV['headless'] == 'true'
       if page.status_code == 200
        check_xss_script
      end
    end
end
```

I hope this could be helpful for anyone in a similar position.